# Change style of table cells on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the color of specific table cells when clicking a button.

```
<button onclick="highlight()">Toggle highlighting</button>
```

And JS:

```
function highlight() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('best');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x.get(i).style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

I added the table cells I want to change to the class "best", but when clicking the button, nothing changes. I first tried to assign them all to a single ID and use `document.getElementById('best').style.color = "green";`, but this only changed the first element that had the id "best" and not all. How should `highlight()` look like?

Comment: `x.get(i)` should just be `x[i]`. There's no `get()` method.

Comment: `x.get(i)` ?? just pass the index `x[i]`

Comment: Don't you get an error message from that line?

Comment: @Barmar Oh thanks it works with `x[i]`. I don't know, I use pycharm (part of django app) and it suggested me this method and no, no error message

Comment: Did you actually check the browser console for errors? I get "TypeError: x.get is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `x.get(i)` there. Just access the element using `x[i]`

See the following code:

```
function highlight() {
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName('best');
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.color = "green";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd recommend using Javascript's built in forEach() function when working with a nodeList like this as there is less chance of an off by one error:

```
bestElements.forEach(best => {
  best.style.color = "green";
});
```

Second, I believe you may be looking for the `background-color` attribute, not the `color` attribute if you are trying to change the color of the entire cell.

```
bestElements.forEach(best => {
  best.style.backgroundColor = "green";
});
```